# EJS variable in JS file in nodejs app using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a `user` object having `last_level` property
I am passing it in my express route as follows :

```
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {
    res.render('main.ejs', { user: req.user })
})
```

I want to access it in my JS script file.

After some research, I tried this...

```
var x = <%- user.last_level %>
```

But its not working (not giving me value of last_level to assign it to variale x). Help me out on this please.

This is my whole function -

```
window.onload = function () {
    var x = <%- user.last_level %> 
    if (x === "Easy") {
        console.log("easy")
    } else if (x === "Hard") {
        console.log("hard")
    } else if (x === "Pro") {
        console.log("pro")
    }
    console.log(x)
};
```

Comment: You should try `var x = user.last_level` without tags.

Comment: is your user object loaded before your script file? `var x = user.last_level` though why would you need to set it to a variable if its there already?

Comment: Just a heads up for the future, **But its not working** is about the worst way to "describe" a problem.

Comment: Its giving ```user is not defined
    at window.onload``` error @federico-moretti

Comment: I am loading script file at the bottom of my page. The user object is passed by express. @cracierjack

Comment: @IROC `<%-` and `%>` is only needed in templating. Maybe, `user` is defined locally and not globally.

Comment: @federico-moretti user object is passed by express ```res.render()``` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stringify your variable and see the results. Use the below code in your ejs template

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function () {
            var x =  <%- JSON.stringify(user.last_level) %>
            if (x === "Easy") {
                console.log("easy")
            } else if (x === "Hard") {
                console.log("hard")
            } else if (x === "Pro") {
                console.log("pro")
            }
            console.log(x)
        };
    </script>
```

Alternative solution is

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      <% if (user.last_level == 'Easy') { %>
        console.log("easy")
      <% } else if((user.last_level == 'Hard')  { %>
        console.log("hard")
      <% } else if(user.last_level == 'Pro')  { %>
        console.log("pro")
      <% } %>
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you please specify the error, since I have tried and tested it. It is working. Which solution you have tried.@IROC

Comment: for the first one ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'``` & for second one, I put it in the webpage itself at bottom, it is showing all red code and not matching to any correct syntax format.

Comment: Here is my route call code 
```app.get('/game', (req, res) => {
    res.render('main.ejs', { user: req.user })
})```

Comment: You should use the first solution in `script ` tag. Like I have edited above. Since we are using `JSON.stringify ` function. 

And you might be observing red code since you are not having `ejs` support in your editor.